# GET (query string) variables in Express.js on Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, post, get, mongodb-atlas

Good guys,
I wrote the express API which works perfectly well when tested with POSTMAN but couldn't do same when i try to get a responds displayed on the browser. Would be glad to know where i went wrong from my code base.

Thanks.

My code base below:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bdclRoutes = require('./routes/bdcl.routes');

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
});
mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Connected to database successfully....')
}).on('error', () => {<br/>
    console.log('Database connection failed.....')
});


const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // res.send('Welcome to BDCL student API')
});
app.use('/api/2020/bdcl_students/uploads', express.static('./uploads'));
app.use('/api/2020', bdclRoutes);


app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server started and app running at port ${process.env.PORT}`)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code looks fine. Something might be blocking your port. Change your port number and try again.

Comment: Thanks Basil.

Noticed that i have another api on that port of which i changed it and it worked.